# I am having issues with CORS. I have set up a ConfigSource bean and also disabled it in http filterchain

Tags: spring-boot-security

Code of SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorization -> authorization
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Also I did this but does not work

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

I keep getting 401 in all cases

I have added beans and other config files as stated, but no luck